# Display Linux text file in the browser

Tags: shell, html

Folks,

I have log file in Linux(RedHat). I want the log file display in the windows web browser . how can i achieve this ? i Googled almost all the pages talks about Web in Linux.Not linux in Web.

Comment: Why can't you use the terminal for your sysadmin  duties? And **Why do you ask?** Please edit your question to improve it and motivate it. Using the browser to look inside log files is probably a bad idea.

Comment: The question mistakenly understood seeing log files inside the server with the help of browser. Nope the question is to check the log file out side the linux box and checking over the browser

Comment: You probably should consider installing Linux on your laptop, notably to learn to use Linux wisely.

Comment: If it is your server then it must have some shared folder which is exposed to apache server which id your website if its eg `www.abc.com` then you must be having `abc.com` as a folder put your file in this directory now it exposed to internet and you can access it from anywhere in the world from browser.provided you must have a web server installed there i.e. `apache` or `apache2`

Comment: You still need to motivate your question. Why do you want to look into a remote log file thru a Windows browser? Why can't you remote login to the Linux system? Your question smells badly like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Without motivations, your question is unclear. I voted to close it.

Answer (score 1):

For a file `/var/log/message.log` sitting on your local machine (the Linux desktop on which you run a browser) you could open
the `file:///var/log/message.log` [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) in your browser.

BTW, doing so is probably a bad idea. I strongly recommend using the terminal and shell utilities (such as [less(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html) or [grep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html)) to inspect log files and to administrate your system.

Alternatively, write your own Linux program which uses some HTTP *server* library like [libonion](http://coralbits.com/libonion/), use in it some fancy AJAX, Javascript (perhaps JQuery) and WebSockets tricks to display nicely the *evolving* log file. Such a project could take you a few weeks (please consider making it opensource). Notice that [libonion](http://coralbits.com/libonion/) provides a [oterm](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion/tree/master/examples/oterm) example which shows a Linux terminal inside your browser (even if the browser is running on some other machine). You could try that (to run Linux commands thru a Windows browser).

Look also into [webmin](http://webmin.com/); it is a web interface for remote Linux administration.

Consider also [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY), an SSH client for Windows able to remotely access and login into some Linux server (having an SSH server).

You could also install and configure a Web server on the remote Linux computer and make that serve your log files (be aware that showing log files to everyone is a security risk).

Answer (score 0):

This does the wonder. `"python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8155"` run with your preferred open port and you can access all the files in the browser.